# Mask sensitive data in exception log spring boot-slf4j

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, java-8

I am working on spring boot micro service application .(java 8,Spring boot,slf4j for logging)
Using fire store as database  and deployed in google cloud.

```
try{
 some code //service call and will hit db
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new MyException("Some error occurred " e);

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new MyException("Error occurred " e);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred " + e);
        }
```

Is there any chance of showing sensitive information while throwing exception.
I read some where that ,for fatal errors,error should not be filtered

Thanking you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance of showing sensitive information while throwing exception?
R: Yes, but this entirely depends on how your application is making use of the information and how the sensitive information could be integrated into log/error outputs.
At the Java side the exceptions are going to be conformed by the class stack trace, which I don't think it could include any sensitive information, the error messages could be the only leaking point but again, those depends on your logging strategies/practices.

I read some where that ,for fatal errors,error should not be filtered...
R: This corresponds to the strategy to analyse and use logs into your app, the answer relies in the same fact that those are mostly coded by you.

Comment: Thank you  @serigo franco .In my code,i am not logging any sensitive information.My question  is whether there is any chance of showing  detailed information as part of exception stack trace.Instead of throwing detailed stack trace i can show e.getCause() or e.getMessage()

Comment: The e.getCause() or e.getMessage() is the most descriptive part of the error, and for instance when the error comes from a resource that you are consuming like DB connections it's probable that an id could appear, so I think you could clear such kind of logs, mostly you are also able to configure the log level at both DB and application. 
If such messages are controlled by you then the you just have to keep them in mind, if they are not, then you could attempt to clear them.